# Flaw in a logic reasoning about limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, logic, definition

I have a question about an exercise from a multiple-choice test from the subject Analysis I, in the first year of Mathematics degree. The question (translated from Spanish) goes like this:

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$  be a function and $a \in \Bbb R, l \in \Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \neq l$. Then:

(i) [statement1]

(ii) [statement2]

(iii) [statement3]

It then gave possible answers like "all of them are true", "only (i) is true" etc. The correct one according to the test was "none of them is true", and I think that (i) should be true.

(i) stated this:

For some $\delta \gt 0$, there exists $\varepsilon  \gt 0$ and $x \in (a-\varepsilon,a+ \varepsilon), x \neq a$ such that $\vert f(x)-l \vert \geq \delta$.

This is very similar to the negation of having limit $l$ in a ((1) from now on), but with some modifications. First, here $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ play the opposite role of the one the usually have in a conventional definition. This is just for making it a little bit more confusing. Second, and the important one, when we negate the property of having limit $l$ in $a$, we should have "For some $\delta \gt 0$ and for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$..." instead of "For some $\delta \gt 0$, there exist $\varepsilon \gt 0$...", according to the use of letters in (i).

Now, I discussed with some other students, and a lot of them say that what the answer wanted us to say is that (i) is not equivalent to (1), but (i) is so similar to (1) that it looks that you wanted us to think that (i) is not what it should be, so (i) is false. I disagree though, because the similarities that (i) and (1) are "just coincidences", so the truth value of (i) should be given with independence of it being equivalent or not to (1). If we look at it like this, then, as (1) is given, in particular, it happens for, $\varepsilon=1$, for example. Then (i) is true, because there exist $\delta, \varepsilon, x$ which satisfy it.

I think that the reasoning involved for saying (i) is false is completely wrong, and it should be no way to justify it. Anyways, other students say that it should be understood that the question wants us to decide wether (i) is equivalent to (1), because both are very similar, and I've also asked my professor by email, and he has said that he didn't understand the question, and we will discuss it in class.

I added all the context because it think it might be reasonable to assume that the exercise wants something that isn't explicitly written, as it is a multiple-choice test.

Am I crazy or (i) is a true statement, and I'm interpreting it correctly? Is it ambiguous?

Comment: Pablusky, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: I've never seen the definition of $\lim_{x \to a} (x) \neq l$, but only the definition of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$. Is it the negation of $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$, or does it mean that the limit exists AND it is not equal to $l$? The difference between these two interpretations matters.

Comment: I think you're correct. Provided that we take $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to just be variables (and ignoring the way in which we usually treat them), this is just the negation of the statement that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = 1$. If we just swap $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, it becomes (equivalent to, since I'll reword it): "there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists $x$ with $0 < |x-1| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(1)| \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: If I had to guess, I think your professor is trying to emphasize that the exact names of the variables in a logical quantification makes absolutely no difference. Even if we've come to know the conventional $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, we could just as well call it the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition and interchange their roles entirely.

Comment: The question would be much easier to read if you told us what the 3 statements $(i)$, $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ are. Or if you focus on $(i)$, maybe you could rephrase the question as a True or False question?

Comment: With the limit I mean the negation of the definition of having limit l. It needn't exist. Also (ii) and (iii) aren't very related to (i), they only use the same function to ask for cpmpletely different thing.

Comment: Did the "Professor" go through this in Class ? What was the outcome ?

Comment: He didn't. But he finally answered my question and he said that it was intended to decide wether i) was the negation of having limit l in a, independently of its truth value

Comment: Oh ok , then clearly it is not the negation of having the limit , because either (1) it is not matching the order of the quantifiers in the negation or (2) it is less restrictive or (3) it is more restrictive : It is not the negation of having the limit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the way you worded it, it is clear that (i) is true. Pick $x_0\neq a$ such that $f(x_0)\neq\ell$ and then $\delta=|f(x_0)-\ell|$ and $\varepsilon$ large enough so that $x_0$ lies in $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$. It is not the negation of the statement $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$, for that would be (after interchanging $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$),
$$\text{for some }\delta>0, \text{for all }\varepsilon>0, \text{if }x\in(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon) \text{ with }x\neq a, \text{ then }|f(x)-\ell|\geq\delta$$
This is very clearly different from the statement given. However, due to what I said in the first paragraph, the statement is a complicated way of writing $f(x)\neq\ell$ for some $x\neq a$. Rewrite this as
$$\text{for some }x\neq a, \text{ we have }|f(x)-\ell|>0$$
and then
$$\text{for some }\varepsilon>0\text{ and }x\in(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\text{ with }x\neq a, \text{ we have }|f(x)-\ell|>0$$
and then
$$\text{for some }\delta>0,\ \text{for some }\varepsilon>0\text{ and }x\in(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\text{ with }x\neq a, \text{ we have }|f(x)-\ell|\geq\delta$$
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

Pick any $\varepsilon > 0$ (arbitrarily large), any $x \neq a$ in $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$ with $f(x) \neq l$, and $\delta = |f(x)-l|$, and $(1)$ is true.

This is always possible unless $f(x) = l$ for all $x \neq a$, and in that case the limit would be $l$.

The whole statement $(1)$ is just supposed to confuse you.

Comment: I did exactly the same reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[[ Commenting in Answer Box to use MathJAX .... ]]

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit

It is like this :
$$(\forall \epsilon) (\exists \delta) (\forall x) (x \in (p - \delta,p + \delta)) \implies \cdots$$
( We can change $\epsilon$ & $\delta$ , though that is not the Concern here )

OP Question has that $l$ is not the limit & we can negate the limit formulation to a true statement.
That will involve something like this :
$$\lnot [[ (\forall \epsilon) (\exists \delta) (\forall x) (x \in (p - \delta,p + \delta)) \implies \cdots ]]$$
Negating the Quantifiers , we will get :
$$(\exists \epsilon) (\forall \delta) (\exists x) \cdots$$
Variable names were changed , hence it will be :
$$(\exists \delta) (\forall \epsilon) (\exists x) \cdots$$

OP Question Choice is :
$$(\text{ for some } \delta) (\exists \epsilon) \land x \in \cdots$$

**(ISSUE 1)** We can see that $\exists x$ is missing in the given Statement.
Is it $(\exists x)$ or $(\forall x)$ or what ? There is no Quantifier for $x$ here.
It is Imprecise & Incomplete Statement !
Hence it is not true.

**(ISSUE 2)** Even ignoring that ISSUE 1 , we see that $(\text{ for some } \delta)$ is weird :
Does it mean $(\exists \delta)$ ? Then it will not match the negation of the limit , hence it will be wrong. When we make the Negation , Quantifier Order will matter.
Does it mean $(\forall \delta)$ ? Then it should not say " for some " Inaccurately.
Hence it is Wrong & hence it is not true.

**SUMMARY :**
Statement is indeed not true.
It is either Imprecise or Incomplete or Inaccurately or Wrong.
Definitely not true !!

[[ Started to write Comment , which turned out to be Elaborate & long enough to be Answer ]]

Comment: About issue 1: the original question was in spanish and wasn't imprecise, because the exist was in plural, so I traduced it imprecisely thinking it sould be understood. About issue 2, i though that it was clear that for some in natural language means existence in formal language. Anyways, why do you say it wouldn't be true? The quantifiers are in the same order as in the negation of the limit, except that (for all ε) is changed by (there esist ε), which is less restrictive than the negation, which was given information. So why would it ve false?

Comment: [[1]] Spanish Original was Precise hence we can ignore it : I was guessing that , hence I already mentioned "Even ignoring that ISSUE 1 ..." : Ok moving to next Point [[2]] Order in negation is $\exists \forall \exists$ , whereas Choice has $\exists \exists \exists$ : It is not Equivalent. Every time limit is true , negation must be false. Every time limit is false , negation must be true. When we make it less restrictive or more restrictive , that will not be Equivalent !

Comment: But I'm not trying to prove that it is equivalent, which certainly isn't. I just say that, uf we have an statemente which is less restrictive than other one, then the latter implies the former. And this is the case: I am given that f doesn't have limit l in a, and then I try to prove (i) which is similar to what I had, but less restrictive.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about that. It is a complicated situation. When we take the given Criteria to mean "the limit exists at $a$ & that limit is not $l$" , then it might be less restrictive. When we take the given Criteria to mean "the limit may not exist at $a$ & if that limit exists , then that limit is not $l$" , then it might be more restrictive.

Comment: **Point** to be careful of [[1]] $\forall [ \cdots ]$ may go less restrictive to $\exists [ \cdots ]$ [[2]] $\exists \forall [ \cdots ]$ may not go less restrictive to $\exists \exists [ \cdots ]$

Comment: Last Comment ( MSE is warning about too many comments ) before closing this Issue (A) Consider $\forall x : 2x = EVEN$ : We can make it less restrictive to $\exists x : 2x = EVEN$ (B) Consider $\exists x \forall y : xy = EVEN$ : We can let $x=2$ to make it true , without us worrying about $y$ value. It is not less restrictive to make it $\exists x \exists y : xy = EVEN$ , because $x=1$ will make us worry about $y$ value which can not be $1,3,5$. Here $y$ has become more restrictive now ! ( We could have better examples though the question is not about that & the comment box is insufficient )